# C++ equivalent of Python's __init__

Tags: python, c++

While learning to code in C++, in a lot of situations I need code to run when I declare the class like giving variables values. I know in Python you can just use `__init__`, but how would I do this in C++?

Comment: please make sure to read the comments on your accepted answer, as there are problems with it.

Comment: `__init__` does not run when a class is declared. It's run whenever ne instance of that class is created.

Comment: that's what i meant i just didn't know what word to use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent of Python's `__init__` method in C++ is called a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). The role of both is to initialize/construct instance of class to be usable. There are some differences, though.

- In Python, data members are initialized inside `__init__`, whereas in C++ they should be initialized using an initializer-list.
- In C++, a constructor by default chains to the default constructor of the parent class, whereas in Python you have to explicitly call the parent `__init__`, preferably through `super()`.
- C++ allows function overloading, which extends to constructors. That allows to declare different constructors with different signatures (argument lists). To do the same in Python you have to declare `__init__` as accepting `*args,**kwargs` and manually dispatch based on those.
- In C++ there are spacial kinds of constructors, namely [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

## Example

Python:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print "Foo ready"
```

C++:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int x;
    Foo(int x) : x(x)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo ready\n";
    }
};
```